# Developing iphone app for an enterprise

Tags: iphone, deployment

We are developing an enterprise application and I looked at the following options:
**1. Putting on itunes.**
Cannot do this since our application is to be used only by our clients with a login and passwrod.
You cannot have login based app in itunes:
http://appreview.tumblr.com/post/952395621/cannot-be-intended-for-a-limited-audience

**2. Using iOS Developer Enterprise**
Cannot do this as : 
The iOS Developer Enterprise Program should be used to develop and distribute proprietary in-house applications to your own employees within your own company. As such, your company would not qualify for direct Program enrollment in this situation. We would suggest that your client apply for enrollment in the Program, and, once enrolled in the Program, your client may add the appropriate developers from your company to their iOS Development Team.

Our client cannot add us.

**3. Adhoc distribution.**
This is only for 100 beta testers.

So are there any other options if I want our client to donwload our app.

Comment: Why can't your client add you? It's a button in the iOS dev portal.

Answer (score 1):

Provide some minimal functionality to all users that does not require any proprietary data, but have the app download all proprietary data and enable proprietary features only after your enterprise customer logs in.  Then submit it to the App store.

There are plenty of examples in the app store.  Banking apps: they might advertise the bank, have maps to the nearest branch, perhaps include a calculator of some sort, but of course don't allow any actual banking features or download any account information until after a customer logs in.  Security apps: provide a public weather web cam view to everybody, but a security cam view only to people who buy their expensive $100K security camera system.

The example private golf course app could have included public information on the club, the current weather, map info on local restaurants, and maybe who to contact to apply for the $10M membership, but then added private club info (calendar, roster) only to paid members after log in.

Make sure to create a test account with dummy (non-proprietary) data and give it to Apple.

Comment: Apps are routinely rejected for only "providing minimal functionality". That is not a viable solution. Your banking app comparison is not accurate in this case as those apps provide plenty of functionality.

Comment: There are also examples of recently accepted apps that do little more than publish a restaurant menu, a tell-a-friend email connection, and provide a Google map to the location of a single restaurant.  Many businesses should be able to provide at least that minimal level of content (on top of the proprietary content only visible/downloaded after logging in).

Comment: @ShaggyFrog : The Chase Bank app only provide a few phone numbers and maps to the nearest branches (unless you are an account holder and log in).  That's not "plenty".

Comment: You misunderstand. Having an account is a bonafide requirement for a banking app. The app itself *does* have "plenty" of functionality. The reason that doesn't apply here is that obviously Chase is going to have a huge number of customers compared to the OP's situation, which absolutely screams "enterprise developer account". For that reason alone, Apple might reject a submission through the regular store.

Comment: @ShaggyFrog : Enterprise accounts are not suitable for any distribution to clients, only to employees of the enterprise.  For  non-employee clients with stock OS devices, it's currently either Ad Hoc distribution (under 100 devices max, including repair replacements and upgrades, and requiring periodic renewal of provisioning), or the iTunes App Store.

Comment: From the OP's question, "We are developing an enterprise application". Until I read something different, it's clear they need an enterprise developer account.

Comment: The OP's question specifically says he can't use an enterprise account

Comment: @ShaggyFrog : You can read something different the next line down from your quote which makes it clear that they can not use an enterprise developer account.

Comment: Right, because his client won't add him. That doesn't mean the enterprise program isn't suitable, only that the OP's client is plagued with some kind of bureaucracy. *We are developing an enterprise application*, but our enterprise client doesn't want us to use the enterprise program.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely have a login based app. I have helped someone submit one that got approved that sounds very similar to the one you are describing. Also, think about the Netflix app for example, login based, limited to Netflix users (although this is probably not as limited as you are talking about).

Comment: The problem with using NetFlix or Chase is that anyone (more or less) can sign up with NetFlix or Chase and use the app. That situation is contraindicated by the question as it is posed.

Comment: It's true that the audience for a NetFlix or Chase app is quite a bit larger than what the OP has in mind, they are still limited audience, login-based apps. That's all I was saying, that login-based apps ARE allowed. I recently helped someone submit an app for car dealerships that require you to buy a car then get a login and pin and it got approved.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is clearly "Using iOS Developer Enterprise"...
Can you be more explicit about the "Our client cannot add us." ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your client to sign up to the iOS enterprise agreement so that they can install it on their phones, and you are simply a team member for them. That also shifts the liability for the app onto them, should anything go wrong.